# Center button in Android browser

Tags: android, css, twitter-bootstrap

I can't seem to get the "Download dbiScript" button on [dbiscript.com](http://dbiscript.com) to center in the Android browser (on my Samsung Galaxy S2).

I'm using Bootstrap on the page. The enclosing `<p>` inherits `text-align: center`.

I've tried styling the enclosing <p> directly, i.e. `<p style="text-align:center"> ...`

I also tried using `margin:auto` on the button itself.

In a simple test, I created a test page with just this:

```
<p style="text-align:center"><button>Test</button></p>
```

The button is centered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the enclosing `<p>` inherits `display: block`.

Changing it to `display: inline-block` fixed the problem.